# In-App purchase testing on production environment without spending money

Tags: objective-c, in-app-purchase, sandbox, production-environment

I have an iOS app which I am about to release on the App store. I want to test In-App purchases in production environment. How I can test In-App purchases for production app which has not been released yet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to itunesConnect , Users and Roles, Create a sandbox user .
I am thinking you have already made the in app purchase items in your app in itunes connect. 
Now in your device log out the Appstore ID from settings.
Do the in app purchase using the Test user credentials you created, and it will make the in app using a sandbox environment.

For more info about In App follow this [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial)

Cheers

Answer (score 5):

The answer is 'NO'.
For app that has not been release on App Store, you can test your IAP items in sandbox  environment ONLY.