# Metadata rejected - To re-submit or not?

Tags: ios, app-store, metadata, app-store-connect

My newly submitted iOS app came up for review after 6 days, however shortly after the status change I got a message saying the metadata was rejected. The following message was posted in the resolution centre:

> We began the review of your app but aren't able to continue because we
>   need additional information about your app.
>
> At your earliest opportunity, please review the following question(s)
>   and provide as much detailed information as you can. The more
>   information you can provide upfront, the sooner we can complete your
>   review.
>
> *List of questions*
>
> **Once you reply to this message in Resolution Center with the requested information, we can proceed with your review.**

Whilst the information on https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html
asks you to re-sumbit the app after providing the necessary information, I have come across some posts which suggest not doing so. Does anyone have any recent experience with this.

The text in bold (in their original message) does not explicitly instruct me to re-submit, but implies that they only need me to answer their message.

After submitting the reply, I still get the following message:
There are one or more issues with the following platform(s):
1 unresolved iOS issue

Any thoughts on this are most welcome

Comment: What are the questions? and you would need to give apple ample data for them to test your application like a test user if your application has a social networking part.

Comment: Hi, yes, I have provided all this information. The questions asked were mostly about subscription and subscription fees, information which I have provided.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the question and Answer ask by apple properly. Also make a pdf if needed to check your App Flow. If there is no change in your code, so no need to submit the binary again. Just resubmit the already submitted metadata.

If changes in code, so upload it again with description what you changes done in this new Metadata.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok as OP said the questions were most probably about subscriptions and IAP.
You need to create a Test Sandbox user and give that user as the demo account and write down furthur instructions that the test user is meant for IAP in the description box.

Apple dev's are probably complaining that you have implemented subscriptions or IAP but they cannot try that out. 
Please follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32391201/3755838) to see how to create a test sandbox user