# In App Purchase functionality is not present in your binary

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

[image: This is what I am getting in my iTunes connect]App store is rejecting my app for below reason but I am able to test with my test device and making purchase for app through sandbox environment . I have submitted this app to app store two time and I got rejection. I need someone to help me over this.

**1 - How to test in app purchase through production IPA to know what they is getting wrong.**

January 29, 2016 at 3:31 AM
From Apple
Abandoned Batch
We found that while you have submitted In App Purchase products for your app, the In App Purchase functionality is not present in your binary.

If you would like to utilize In App Purchase in your app, you will need to upload a new binary that incorporates the In App Purchase API to enable users to make a purchase.

Your help will be more than appreciation!

[**This is my in-app purchases product**[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaRS6.png)
[[image: **This is what I am getting under in-app purchases of build**]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9yTK.png)
[[image: **Is this necessary to get my in-app purchase under this while submitting**]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ML0gH.png)

Comment: Can you put code used here?

Comment: What is your question? Check the tab Capabilities in Xcode and disable In-App Purchase if you are not using it

Comment: Ok allright @lorenzoliveto app is capable for making in app purchase.

Comment: I am able to purchase item from app but nevertheless app store is rejecting with this same massage friend @AvijitNagare

Comment: Try asking them what is the problem with your implementation of in-app purchase. It seems that they can't find it in the app. I usually make a video showing the functionality to them.

Comment: That is good option @lorenzoliveto but I have written all the steps which can lead them to reach at app purchase functionality, so I want to know if I can see or check that IPA on my device! anything like that

Comment: I think that you can't test the IAP in the production environment. Check out these answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498005/ios-in-app-purchase-test-a-real-purchase-without-submitting-to-apple http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32391041/in-app-purchase-testing-on-production-environment-without-spending-money

Comment: Thanks for you support @lorenzoliveto can you show me some cheklist which will help me to find a problem in it

Comment: Hey @lorenzoliveto I don't know but is it important in-app purchase status approved please reply.

Comment: Hello @AvijitNagare I really running out of time! would you love to help me

Comment: The only think I con point out to you is the official IAP documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html) and the tutorials on Ray Wenderlich's site that are always very helpful

Comment: Can't predict exact issue refer http://www.raywenderlich.com/105365/in-app-purchases-tutorial-getting-started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is so ridiculous but it will helpful for anyone like me in future
so problem was In-App Purchase and Submitting Binary

Please if you are submitting app binary for in - app purchase first time don't submit your in - app purchase first.

submit your build or binary with In-App Purchase selected under you build screen as shown in screenshot[image: It shows when you go to Feature tap]

Comment: OMG, I've submitted so many apps and IAPs and managed to forget this, this time. App Store Connect is a minefield of checkboxes and magic.

Comment: I can only see one screenshot. where are the second and third one?

Comment: Please clarify the fix. "Please if you are submitting app binary for in - app purchase first time don't submit your in - app purchase first."

Answer (score 2):

Here 2 possible reasons for why the rejected App:

- First is might be you are submitting wrong binary. Make sure you are submitting latest binary with in App purchase integrated
- Second is if you are submitting right build that might be apple testers not able to find in App purchase option while testing App. In that case you can provide more information to them about how they will get in App purchase option

In Second case try this:

- Below apple rejection reason you can see an option where you can appeal to them.
- Using that send apple information about where in the app they will get an in App purchase option. Also provide him information by this in App purchase what it will change in the App.

Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Hello @mack I have did that process and they have replied me for same -: In App Purchase functionality is not present in your binary.

Comment: No @mac I am new in it so I don't know what meta data is but under in-app purchases on iTunesConnect my in-app purchase product is in "In Review" state

Comment: I can see that [environment : sandbox] for buy my product and it is purchasing product. we have submitted this binary in which we are testing this test accounts. and I don't recognise why this issue is happening.

Comment: is it necessary to submit binary for review with selected in-app purchase product under "In-App Purchases" option of iTunesconnect.

Comment: now I am figuring it out; So could you tell me that,I need my in-app purchase product under this and this is to be added while submitting my app to app review am I right ?

Comment: first is my in-app purchase product and rest of this are testing and that I don't to be configured in my app.

Comment: Yes exactly that needs to be added